# SSIS package connecting to Excel receiveserror DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a connection to Excel that fails every run.  Debugger doesn't show which steps have run but show a red X over steps retrieving data from Excel.

Clicking the Progress tab shows the error DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

How do I get the package to run in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Was running in 64-bit mode.  Setting project properties -> Debugging -> Run64BitRuntime to false allowed me to debug.